# How to get a set of not null documents in FaunaDB

Tags: faunadb

I am going along [this official tutorial](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/learn/tutorials/fql/basics/data_modeling#bindings) and I create a similar index.

Below is my code that calculate the difference of a `start` and an `end`, which `end` is nullable.

```
CreateIndex({
  name: "foo_index",
  source: {
    collection: Collection("bar_collection"),
    fields: {
      interval: Query(
        Lambda(
          "bazDoc",
          If(
            Or(
              IsNull(Select(["data", "start"], Var("bazDoc"), null)),
              IsNull(Select(["data", "end"], Var("bazDoc"), null))
            ),
            null,
            Subtract(
              Select(["data", "end"], Var("bazDoc")),
              Select(["data", "start"], Var("bazDoc"))
            )
          )
        )
      )
    }
  },
  values: [
    { binding: "interval"},
    { field: ["ref", "id"]}
  ]
})
```

This is the return, which I want to filter out all docs that the `interval` is null. How should I achieve this.

```
{
  data: [
    [9, "353542771515064533"],
    [10, "353542807600758997"],
    [null, "353542787197567188"],
    [null, "353542814197350613"]
  ]
}
```

Btw, I'm new to FaunaDB, please suggest some resources to learn other than Fauna's own document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [docs state](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/fql/indexes#values)

> When a document is indexed, and all of the index’s defined `values` evaluate to `null`, no index entry is stored for the document.

Since you are also including the ref ID, which is never `null`, there will always be an index entry created.

However, you can add another binding that also returns null in case the interval is null or the Ref otherwise. This way, both values will be null, and no entry will be created.

```js
CreateIndex({
  name: "foo_index",
  source: {
    collection: Collection("bar_collection"),
    fields: {
      interval: Query(
        Lambda(
          "bazDoc",
          If(
            Or(
              IsNull(Select(["data", "start"], Var("bazDoc"), null)),
              IsNull(Select(["data", "end"], Var("bazDoc"), null))
            ),
            null,
            Subtract(
              Select(["data", "end"], Var("bazDoc")),
              Select(["data", "start"], Var("bazDoc"))
            )
          )
        )
      ),
      ref: Query(
        Lambda(
          "bazDoc",
          If(
            Or(
              IsNull(Select(["data", "start"], Var("bazDoc"), null)),
              IsNull(Select(["data", "end"], Var("bazDoc"), null))
            ),
            null,
            Select(["ref"], Var("bazDoc"))
          )
        )
      )
    }
  },
  values: [
    { binding: "interval" },
    { binding: "ref" }
  ]
})
```

I’ve included the whole Ref as the value here, which is what I recommend. It makes it easier to reuse in combination with other queries, and all the drivers let you use the Ref values in additional queries and get the ID like `ref.id` in your app where you need it.

> please suggest some resources to learn other than Fauna's own document.

I hope that others can also pitch in here, too. I am on the Customer Support team at Fauna and want to highlight that we have [discourse forums](https://forums.fauna.com) and a [discord server](https://discord.gg/5TMu5fCn). Myself and other Fauna employees make a best effort to see that every forums question is addressed in a reasonable time, either by the community, or by answering ourselves; and we’re active in discord, which is better for general discussions.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I was thinking of using intersect to remove null entries. This is way better than my idea. I will try forum and discord server later. It will be amazing if there will be more pet project or case study posted on Medium.